# Using imported CSV column as string in difflib.get_close_matches

Tags: python, difflib

I am a noob when it comes to Python but definitely want to learn more. My project essentially entails importing a column from CSV1 and then using get_close_matches to compare it to the Master column in CSV2 and output anything that is greater than .6 to a new column in CSV1. Everything I have read regarding difflib.get_close matches leads me to believe that I have to specify my string inside the code itself. Here is what I have written so far but it is far from perfect and before I keep going, I figured I might as well figure out if it is even possible. Any help would be appreciated!

https://pastebin.com/8v1hvMbP

```
import sys
import csv
import difflib

infile = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
reader = csv.reader(infile)
infile2 = open(CSV2.csv, "rb")
reader2 = csv.reader(infile2)

diff = difflib.get_close_matches(open(infile).readlines(),open(infile2).readlines())

best_match = difflib.get_close_matches(my_str,str_list,1)[0]
score = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, my_str, best_match).ratio()
for word in str_list:
    print "score for: " + my_str + " vs. " + word + " = " + 
str(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, my_str, word).ratio())

infile.close()
infile2.close()
```

EDIT:I am doing it with pandas now as it seems a lot easier. I have succesfully imported certain columns into my script and I am now trying to run get_close_matches to compare one column to the other.

I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range.

Here is my new code:

```
import sys
import csv
import difflib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
OrgID = df.OrganizationID
MappedID = df.MappedID
best_match = difflib.get_close_matches(OrgID, MappedID, 1)[0]
score = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, OrgID, best_match).ratio()
for word in MappedID:
    print "score for: " + OrgID + " vs. " + word + " = " + str(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, OrgID, word).ratio())
```